# I need to map TS classes array to object { [key: classNameWithFirstLetterLowercase]: classInstance }, can't make it strongly typed

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function. It should accept class definitions and produce object with their names (first letter - lowercase) mapped to their instances. I want it to be strongly typed.

```
function createObject (...classes: any[]) {
    // something like
    return classes.reduce((acc, class) => {
        const name = class.name.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + class.name.slice(1);
        acc[name] = new class();
        return acc;
    });
}
```

So I want to use it like:

```
const { aClass, bClass, cClass } = createObject(AClass, BClass, CClass);
```

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to extract class name like this:

```
type GetName<T> = 'name' extends keyof T ? T['name'] : never;
type ClassName = GetName<AClass>;
```

But ClassName is never. Guess I'm missing something crucial.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't know that `AClass.name` is `"AClass"`, and without support for a `nameof` type operator as requested in [ms/TS#1579](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1579) it can't know this.  If you try a "fixed" version of your code (e.g., `GetName<typeof AClass>` you'll see that it's `string`, which isn't helpful to you, right?.  If you want the compiler to know that `AClass.name` is `"AClass"` you'll have to add that information explicitly, at which point you should probably change the approach entirely.  See the answer to the linked question for more information.

Comment: Yeah. Thx. In the end I finished up with array implementation.